# Google Maps Android можно ли использовать бесплатно?

Tags: android-studio, google-maps-api

Здраствуйте,
мне нужно в приложении показать фрагмент карты с местоположением барбершопа и так же я хочу что бы пользователь мог переходить в приложение гугл мапс для постройки маршрута.
Вопрос в том могу ли я это сделать бесплатно, нужно ли подключать биллинг в google cloud? и нужно ли регистровать приложение в этом разделе гугл клоуд "OAuth consent screen".
И если я не могу использовать это бесплатно то какие аналоги?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать бесплатно, но для этого желательно будет создать отдельный аккаунт чтобы отображать место на карте при регистрации будет: ввести адрес организации - внизу нажать слева на ссылку, и отмечаете место на карте

Comment: Я уже использую проект в firebase и он автоматом создается в Google Cloud.
Или вы имеете введу регистрацию:
OAuth consent screen
Choose how you want to configure and register your app, including your target users. You can only associate one app with your project.

User Type

Internal

External
???

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду регистрацию

Comment: Я извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос... но я просто не могу понять для чего нужна эта регистрация: OAuth consent screen
в самом приложении Google Maps организация уже существует, мне просто нужно в моем приложении отметить ее

Comment: и мне дает только возможность выбрать:
External
Available to any test user with a Google Account. Your app will start in testing mode and will only be available to users you add to the list of test users. Once your app is ready to push to production, you may need to verify your app. Learn more